# Why arent both of these functions working for my html js button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button on a page which I have programmed to scroll to the next div in a large container. However, I also want the same button to scroll the browser window over a certain amount of pixels whenever I scroll to the left or the right of the page.

Here is what I have tried:
This scrolls the container over a div. Then I tried adding a function that said scroll window from "getOffset"

```
var colwidth = $('#container').width(),
contwidth = $('#contents').width(),
getOffset = function() {
    return parseInt($('#container').css('margin-left'));
};

$(".left").click(function(){
   if (getOffset() === 0) return false;
   function scrollWindow(scrollValue) {

        window.scrollBy(getOffset, 0);

    }
    $("#contents").animate({left: '+=' + colwidth},500);
    $("#container").animate({'margin-left': '-=' + colwidth},500);
 });
$(".right").click(function(){
    if (getOffset() === contwidth - colwidth) return false;

    $("#contents").animate({left: '-=' + colwidth},500);
    $("#container").animate({'margin-left': '+=' + colwidth},500);
    function scrollWindow(scrollValue) {

        window.scrollBy(getOffset, 0);

    }
 });

</script>
```

Logically to me it seems like it should work, but my page ignores the function to scroll the window over. I would appreciate any help. Where is my logic wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Not exactly sure what `scrollBy` expects but should it be `window.scrollBy(getOffset(), 0);`?

Comment: scrollBy was meant to be a function using the getOffset as a parameter.

Comment: Ok, wasn't sure if it needed the value returned by `getOffset` or the function `getOffset` itself.

Comment: sorry I should have included that. I thought if I could use the value from one of the functions from within another, it would work.

Answer (score 0):

To attach event handlers to dynamic elements, use the [jQuery .on() method if you're using jQuery 1.7+](http://www.andismith.com/blog/2011/11/on-and-off/). If you are using older versions, choose among .bind(), .delegate(), and .live() jQuery methods.

Comment: I tried that also:  $("#contents").animate({left: '+=' + colwidth},500).bind('onclick'); All of my js code just stops working